# Swift: How to remove all text in a string before comma

Tags: swift, string

I have a String : `"Doe, John"`. How would I remove all of the text before the word "John" so that it would be `"John"` removing both the comma and the last name.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string?changes=latest_minor In the documentation of `String`, there is an example keeping only "Marie" from `"Marie Curie"`, where character "stop" is a space. In your case, it's a comma, and you want the other part of the range, but that should be a good start, no? There are other solutions with `componentsSeparated(by:)` but that might be more complex for a small task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
let str = "John, Doe"
let array = str.split(separator: ",")
print("\(array.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? "")")
```

prints

```
Doe
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I would also recommend using the documentation Larme has provided in the comments